# How can I create a cross-site DVWP in 2010?

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part, data, cross-site

This was so easy in SharePoint Designer 2007 - you just used the "Connect to another library..." link and you could quickly create a DVWP on your page that used any list/library in your site collection.

Is there a way to easily do this in SharePoint Designer 2010? Marc Anderson [has a post](http://sympmarc.com/2010/11/02/using-a-datasource-in-a-data-view-web-part-dvwp-in-a-different-site-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/) about messing a bit with the code to reproduce but that's not quite the Easy Button I'm hoping for. Neither is using Web Services. Both are fine enough as approaches but they're a both a little too fragile to recommend to some of our power users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect to another library in sharepoint 2010 does not exist, they for some reason removed it. But I did find another method being used using sharepoint designer...I dont know if it would be any use to you ;)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SfpgoEUlIw

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks - that appears to be the best way to go about it. MS never fails to amaze.

Answer (score 0):

With my Item Lister & Item Viewer web parts, you can fetch data from any list or library in a site collection without writing any code. You can check them out at: http://www.spwp.net

Have a nice day...